# How to exclude objects from light sources in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

Some of my scene objects need a little bit of **extra lighting**, but it would be nice to **exclude the my reflective ground** from that (see the picture bellow).

[image]

**Is there an option in cycles to don't effect objects or exclude objects from lights?**